# how to switch the url based on the condition in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Nowadays i'm dealing with angularjs and i'm newbie . I have been working for authentication for each $http request and url changes. Therefore i have implemented peace of codes for url changing authentication as bellows

```
/** Main Login submit **/    
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log("enter login submit");
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (!$scope.loginForm.$invalid) {
        $scope.login($scope.credentials);
    } else {
        $scope.error = true;
        $scope.error_des = '';
        return;
    }
};

//enter code here

/** checking after loggedin in each url **/
if ($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]) {
        var credentials = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage["userInfo"]);
        $scope.login(credentials);
};

/** Common login **/
$scope.login = function(credentials) {

    $scope.error = false;
    Auth.login(credentials, function(user) {
        //success function
        $mdDialog.hide();
        $state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("error");
        $scope.error_des = err.msg;
        $scope.error = true;
    });
};
```

Everything is working as i expected but while reloding the same page it'l always redirect to home(http://localhost:3000/#/home).i know that it happens because of

```
$state.go("admin-panel.default.home");
```

my question is how to and where give the condition to load same page on reloading??

Comment: Who launches this -> $scope.submit?

Comment: from login button of login-dialog.html

Comment: Have you set otherwise like this $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); or your home html path

Comment: I have  set this in my main app .js for overall url changing! You are telling  to add this in login -controller?

Comment: Will you show to me your html. You have used submit button for login. am i right?

Comment: Do not use submit button

Answer (score 0):

maybe ,you don't have a login state on your app.js file.
so when you are on login page and refresh , you redirect on home page.
if this is not your problem , don't read the rest of my answer.

So, below i show a snippet of my app.js , i have all my states there(my menu redirections) and for the last i use the $urlRouterProvider.otherwise function to redirect the user always in login screen , if they are not logged in.

If my user ,for example ,is on the **login** state , no matter how many times he reloads the page, he will always stay on login page.

I use these modules **$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider** and not the default **$route**  of angularjs.

After my different states, i add the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');`  as last option to be sure that he will not find any ,other hidden or forgotten url.

```
angular.module('MainApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider            
        .state('floorplan', {
            url: '/floorplan/:activeEventId',               
            template: '......',
            onEnter: function () {
               //write code when you enter that state
            },
            onExit: function () {
            //write code when you change state
            }
        })
        .state('seating', {
            url: '/seating',
            template: '<div>Seating is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('event_details', {
            url: '/event/details',
            template: '<div>Event details is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('reports', {
            url: '/reports',
            template: '<div>Reports is under construction</div>'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/assets/modules/login/login.html',
            onEnter: function () {
             //write code when you enter that state
            },
            onExit: function () {
            //write code when you exit that state
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login'); //when no route found redirect to login
});
```

i hope that helps , good luck.